# How to access NFC Secure Element in upcoming BB10 handsets and platform?

Tags: security, api, nfc, blackberry-10

Since straight Java development isn't going to be supported on BB10 (Am I right?), at least not without using the Android Java Runtime (which I don't want to use), I'd like to know if there will be official support and an official API from RIM for accessing and writing on the Secure Element of the upcoming BB10 handsets. I'm a developer who's considering the BB10 platform for developing an application which will need read/write operations on the Secure Element. Would that be possible? Would I be needing special permissions and/or keys from RIM?

Apparently there's not much documentation on the subject so far.

Answer (score 2):

They have removed the SE on BB10 and left only the UICC...And we feel it's a good thing, as there were loads of issues with accessing the SE of a SIM

Comment: The NFC secure element APIs now support, and enforce where appropriate, the Global Platform ACF format. If you were using certain Gemalto SIMs, you may have found that you received the error response NFC_RESULT_SE_REQUEST_REJECTED from the APIs due to a "deny all" rule in the GlobalPlatform ACF applet that Gemalto load onto their SIMs. You should explicitly whitelist any particular AID that you want your application to have access to by providing an "any application can access AID X.Y.Z rule".

Answer (score 1):

After some posting on other forums, I learned that there is indeed an [API](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/beta/reference/com.qnx.doc.nfc/topic/manual/nfc_lib_nfc_conceptual_overview.html) for accessing the SE in the upcoming BB10 platform. It was included in the BlackBerry 10 Native SDK (Beta 2). So far, it seems it serves my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to go to the RIM [issue tracker site](https://www.blackberry.com/jira/), you can get access if you make an account at the [BlackBerry Jam Zone](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/bdsc/home.html). Submit an issue under the BlackBerry 10 project making the business case for what you want to do. They may be able to tell you what their plans are, but there is still some mutability in the road map if you can make a strong enough case.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I'll try and do that. But, I understand that, as far as you know, there is not official announcement and/or support from RIM at this time, right?.

Comment: I wouldn't say that. I haven't looked at NFC API, though IIRC there was something about it in the Beta 2 announcement. Don't know if it applies to your question.

Comment: There's indeed an API for BB10 NFC SE access in Beta 2 Native SDK, Richard. Seems up to the task, so far. Thanks for your help.